# Access Raspberry Pi "Thingsboard" account from outside home?

Tags: cloud, raspberry-pi3, iot, thingsboard

I have installed [Thingsboard cloud platform](https://thingsboard.io/,) on my raspberry pi using [ThingsBoard Installation Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/rpi/).

I access the Raspberry Pi IP address `192.168.xx.xx:8080/login` from another Ethernet connected device. It takes me directly to `Thingsboard WebUI` login page where I successfully log in and access the dashboard, devices etc.

But when I try to connect to it from another home (i.e. from another router than my home router) using the Internet it won't let me connect.

I tried to look for this issue on the Internet but I couldn’t find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already checked if the port 8080 is open to external access in your internet router?

If it is open, you need to check the port forwarding in your internet router (all the incomming traffic at the port 8080 must be directed to IP of your RPi).

Comment: thanks for giving your time,
Yup, I have checked it is not open to external access,

actually I am a complete noob in the field of IOT, raspberry pi and cloud and also i have a very little knowledge about networking as well, 

what i have done is that I have download thingsboard cloud on my raspberry pi and then I test a small lightning LED circuit by monitoring & controlling through dashboard (but I can access it only from other LAN devices and from it's localhost), I have searched alot on internet about how to control and monitor it through internet

Comment: and than I find cloud gateway is used for that and by it we can send data using MQTT, HTTP etc protocols, 

Hope i explain better the situation to u, can u provide some more help to me,I want to know: is really cloud gateway used for controlling and monitoring of dashboard  from any where in the world using Internet, if it not than how can I do this.

again thanks for your reply